# CFSCRIPT - For Loop - How to increment by 50 or 100?

Tags: loops, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 9.  I am not interested in non-CFSCRIPT answers.

I am trying to loop from 0 to 100 by increments of 5.

Here's my normal loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i + 5) {
    writeOutput(i);
}
```

Why isn't this working for me?

Comment: Just an observation, your code you'll never hit the the number 100. You will get 20 iterations but the counter will go from 0 to 95 and stop instead of 100.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, my code was just an example of what I was trying to accomplish, specifically, incrementing the index by a value greater than one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do

```
i = i +5
```

instead of
    i + 5